# Reading \n in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject

I am assigning value to `UILabel`. If I get value from `NSManagedObject` than \n shows as it is and doesn't read it as new line.
Here is my code

```
let cards:Card = cardArray[0] as! Card
lblTitle?.text = cards.title 
//Output in UiLabel is "This is \n title"
```

I want UiLabel to read \n as new line

However below code gives expected output

```
lblTitle?.text = "This is \n title"
```

Comment: `lblTitle.numberOfLines = 0`?

Comment: already set numberOfLines = 0 but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you `title` contains escaped character i.e the reason `\n` is printing try once replacing `\\n` with `\n`.

**Swift 3**

```
lblTitle?.text = cards.title.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n")
```

**Swifr 2.3 or lower**

```
lblTitle?.text = cards.title.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\n", withString: "\n")
```

Comment: Yup thanks its working :) Could you please explain why its add \ during saving

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: I don't know the reason of that `\\` added in to your title it is depend on your initialisation of your title.